# Read cgi raw post data without CGI module in perl

Tags: perl, post, cgi

On my server I don't have CGI installed is it possible to get Raw Post Data without that module? I've try to check the source code for CGI.pm but didn't found anythig.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just install it? (Besides the fact that its use is [discouraged](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE) in favor of [more modern alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).) In the CGI protocol, POST data is simply read from STDIN, but writing your own parameter parsing code from scratch seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I can't install anything, it's shared hosting. I've try to read data from STDIN but it's empty.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot reading from STDIN work after all.

Comment: even on shared hosting: try local::lib http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/local-lib-2.000018/lib/local/lib.pm  or perlbrew. This will often work, enabling you to use cpan, which is a major upside.

Comment: Can you ask the people running the shared hosting to install the module? If they won't, can't you move to a better shared hosting company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract POST data by reading from STDIN. ([Viewing raw POST data](http://www.willmaster.com/blog/cgi/view-post-data.php))

**paramExtractor.cgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $buffer = '';
if($ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}) { read(STDIN,$buffer,$ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}); }
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print 'Post data is (' . length($buffer) . " chars):\n";
if( ! length($buffer) ) { $buffer = '[No POST data received]'; }
print $buffer;
exit;
```

**form.html**

```html
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1/paramExtractor.cgi">
<table cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" style="width:200px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" style="width:200px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td valign="top">Message:</td>
<td><textarea name="message" style="width:200px; height:75px;"></textarea></td>
</tr><tr>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="submit" style="width:200px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think it should be `$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}`

Comment: @jcubic, Useless quotes are useless.